# Can anyone help me understand the idea of conditional independence?

Tags: probability

I understand the measure theoretic definition of conditional independence but am not quite getting the intuition behind it. Can anyone help me understand it?

For example, if you toss a coin twice, the results are independent but are they conditional independent given a third event i.e. the coin is tossed in a certain way?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example.  There are two biased coins.  One of them shows heads $99$ percent of the times you flip it, the other one shows tails $99$ percent of the times you flip it.  You do an experiment where you pick one of the two coins randomly (with equal probability), and then flip the coin twice.  The event $H_1$ that you get heads on the first flip is not independent of the event $H_2$ that you get heads on the second flip.  (If you get heads on the first flip, you probably chose the coin that's biased towards heads, so you will probably get heads on the second flip also.)  However, let $E$ be the event that you choose the coin that's biased towards heads.  Then the events $H_1$ and $H_2$ are conditionally independent given $E$.

Comment: You explained the intuition behind condition independence wrt to an event very clearly. Can you explain the intuition behind condition independence wrt to a random variable?